# Strange speaker bug

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, audio, speakers

I have a Toshiba Satellite L755, with a Intel i3 processor. It came with Windows 7 and, since purchasing it, have installed Windows 8 (upgraded to 8.1) and Ubuntu 13.10 (it's tri-booted, so I have all three).

However, around when I installed Windows 8, my speakers started running into a strange bug: they would work for somewhere around five minutes, then mysteriously stop making any sound. The speaker is still registered as connected and the volume is still on, but it won't make any sound.

After installing Ubuntu, I discovered another part of this problem: whenever I put the computer to sleep, then wake it up again, the speakers work (again) for around five minutes before "muting" again.

EDIT: Just in case this helps, headphones work fine. The problem is specifically with the internal speakers.

Comment: Does this issue of the speaker stopping only occur when using Windows 8 or any OS?

Comment: No, it happens on all of the OS's that I have.

Comment: And you talking about internal or external speaker?

Comment: It's the speakers built into the laptop, so I'm guessing you mean internal?

Comment: Do you have 1 or 2 outputs for sound (1 for speaker and 1 for headphones or is it just headphones)?

Comment: It has two outputs: speaker and headphones. I can only use one at a time though: I'm assuming that is normal.

Comment: Yes. You said the headphones work fine - do they work fine from both ouputs?

Comment: Oh, wait, I guess I misunderstood: there's the speakers built into the laptop, then there's a headphone port.

Comment: What happens if you the speakers are in use? I mean, if you can find a 30 minute audio clip and play it, do the speakers cut out?

Comment: I checked with a 30 minute Nyan Cat (why not?) and it cut out after 2:05 (2 minutes 5 seconds). Sorry for the late reply, I've been somewhat busy lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is odd, but I found a few people with the same issue.

Since it occurs in both OS regardless of driver, the fault is likely to be the motherboard.

[This thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/internal-speakers-stop-working-after-a-minute-of-being-awake-on/m-p/1300053#M53078) explains near identical issue you are having; That the speaker cuts out, and even mentions to put it to sleep and back restores the sound yet the headphones work. Their solution was a new motherboard.

However, this [Toshiba question](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6122_102-600384/toshiba-satellite-speaker-sound-problem/) suggests that you need to return the laptop to factory settings to see if the issue is with hardware or not!  It also a comment (rant) by  Ischan666 on that link (control f for  Ischan666) who mentions the issue is actually hardware but due to the wifi adapter and suggests some tests you can perform.

Others also report disabling and re-enabling the sound in control panel/device manager helps.

Some mention that unplugging and replugging in the battery restores sound.

However, the last 2 points I think are temporary fixes.

Depending on the age of the machine, and assuming everyhting is working fine, I'd suggest buying some portable speakers or earphones/headphones and living with it unless the sound is really that important? If so, restore to factory defaults, test it. If it fails, it's probably the motherboard, fix the board, pay for it to be resolved etc, if it works, then it was a hardware conflict... !

Comment: Okay, thank you. Because the laptop isn't that good anyways, I'm just going to get portable speakers, instead of trying to deal with the internals of the laptop.